# Has any one seen discrepancy in Google desktop search and Google Mobile Search ? Does it means google crawl mobile search prior to desktop search?

Tags: google, google-search, mobile

e.g
Search this phrases in Mobile and Desktop

" restaurant in koregaon park fitlogy "

Check the Titles. Observe Discrepancy

[image: google Desktop]

[image: google Mobile]

Comment: There is definitely a different audience between desktop and mobile. The query engine takes this into account. Mobile is more of an immediate search. Desktop tends to be more research. Most do not search and read academic papers on their mobile and most do no search for restaurants on desktops as much as when they are already out. What you are seeing in the title differences is the *question* Google is attempting to answer. Google does this for both, mobile and desktop, but clearly mobile is used for immediate answers. Why they show the question in the title is a mystery. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

Google is answering a question keyed off of `restaurant in koregaon park` of the search query `restaurant in koregaon park fitlogy`. I tested this using a similar search `restaurant in altoona yamato` and got similar results. However if the search is changed to `yamato restaurant altoona, pa.` the results change significantly. The difference is the semantic clue *in* making a complete subject predicate object *semantic pairing* sentence. Semantic pairs are how the knowledge graph works. The knowledge graph is a semantic links engine that will match restaurants *in*, a semantic pair link, to a location. To Google, the search is `restaurant in koregaon park` +`fitlogy` and not for `fitlogy restaurant in koregaon park` where the semantic clues are subject, descriptor, predicate, object and where `restaurant` describes `fitlogy`. The search could have easily been `fitlogy in koregaon park` with better results.

Mobile users are different. Google understands this. The query engine uses a different set of SERP ranking algorithms for mobile. Mobile searchers are looking for immediate results to satisfy certain types of searches. Both mobile and desktop searches use the answer engine which is a part of the query engine, however, the types of questions will be different and hence why a change in the SERP ranking algorithms. Mobile users expect different results even when the search is specific. This does not preclude a search query from returning the same #1 result for mobile and desktop searches. It just means that search *intent* may be different.

Why Google chose to insert the question being answered by the answer engine as part of the title is beyond me. However, from a user standpoint, this is a good indicator of whether the search query was aimed correctly and therefore could be a good addition to the SERPs page and not added to the title where it could be confusing.

Remember that Google leans heavily on the *answer* side of things and overly optimizes searches based upon search query criteria. This is not the only case where over optimization can be seen. For example, I have cut and pasted a unique part of content into the search bar without quotes and with quotes with different results. With the quotes, the string is taken literally and returns the correct result as the first SERP link. Without the quotes, Google attempts to determine the meaning of the search and returns the correct result much lower. Remember, there is only one page where all the terms exist exactly as I have searched them. While this is to be expected, it tells us one thing. Simple and ordinary search algorithms take a far lower priority than others and some searches fail as a result. Other examples can easily be found searching for academic papers related to information retrieval (IR) systems/algorithms of which search engines rely upon heavily. SEO pages that have little or nothing to do with the search query are returned more times than they should be and any research paper is often pushed very low in the SERPs. Again, trend search over optimization.

So, to clarify, search queries are not taken as literally as people may think and any search that appears to be answerable, regardless of any other terms used, will return results from the answer engine as it has for the OP. Again, semantics plays a huge part of this and search queries can vary widely with just a few minor changes. The OP's search query contained enough clues, in fact, a perfect alignment of minimal clues, to signal a response from the answer engine. It is that simple.

Answer (score 1):

Google can use `<title>` and `<h1>` tag on their search result **based on user query**. And if title and h1 both are missing then they will assign anchor text as title.

In this case the title is "Restaurants in Koregaon Park : Dine at the finest Restaurants in KP" and h1 is "Dine at the finest Restaurants in Koregaon Park"

Here Google return h1 tag, because it is perfect for desktop search while the title tag is more relevant to mobile search, which Google doing from many years.

Do this search and you will see the title tag is used by Google.

```
site:fitlogy.com/restaurants-in-koregaon-park/
```

It's purely based on user query, it is not related to "Google priority of mobile crawling is higher than desktop".

Comment: Hi Goyllo, We have added <title > and <h1>. However, we created different title and H1 tag .